# Creating Blueprints for Robocraft

Tags: game, cad

> Robocraft is a "build, drive, fight" game where the players engage in online battles in order to gain Robo Points (RP) and Tech Points (TP) to further advance their robotic vehicles. With Tech Points, the player can unlock better armour blocks, hardware, and weapons from a tech tree, which they can then purchase with Robo Points.

taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocraft#Gameplay).

Robocraft does not have a sandbox build mode yet(?), in which you can basically build whatever you want, regardless the Robo Point costs of the cubes. This is really unfortunate as I am always running out of Robo Points, when I am half way through with my robot.

Therefore, does anybody know another tool, in which you can easily create blueprints for your robot? The blueprints should contain:

- the vague appearance of the robot
- the amount of different blocks

With vague I mean e.g.: if a gun in the blueprint is only a big cube, that is perfectly fine.

The software itself should be:

- easy to use (no SolidWorks, AutoCAD etc.)
- free or cheap
- (optionally) run on Linux

*Note:* I am really unsure with the tags, as the only fitting tag would be "Robocraft". So feel free to edit them.

Answer (score 1):

While missing one of your requirements I would still suggest investing the time to learn [Blender](http://www.blender.org) 3D modelling tool, as in [this](http://robocraftgarage.com/tutorial/alFLMRT6) tutorial.

- Vague appearance of your robot ***Yes*** or exact if you wish to put in the time
- Count the blocks ***Yes***
- Easy to use *a steep learning curve but **lots** of tutorials on the web and a really good investment of your time*
- Free ***Yes*** both gratis & open source
- Run on Linux ***Yes*** and OS/X and Windows.